# projections of semisimple algbras

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $A$ be a semisimple algebra with decomposition
\begin{align*}
A=\bigoplus\limits_{\pi }^{}n_{\pi }V_{\pi }
\end{align*} into irreducible representations $V_{\pi }$ and assume we have projections $D^{\pi }\in A $ that map into the irreducibles $V_{\pi }$, where $D^{\pi }$ is viewed as a map via left-multiplication. Let furthermore $\rho :A\to \operatorname{end}(V)$ be another representation. I would like to show that $\rho \left(D^{\pi }\right):V\to V$ projects into the irreducible component $V_\pi$ inside of $V$ but I can't find a straightforward argument for that. Is this statement even true in general?